# Error calling Instagram API in python

Tags: python, instagram-api, google-app-engine-python

I call instagram api but this error How can I solve it?

this is my code:

```
 params = {
                "access_token" :"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "count": 1,
                "q": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
            api_uri = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search'

            req = requests.get(api_uri, params = params)
            searched_user_data = json.loads(req.text)
            logging.info(searched_user_data)
```

This is error code:

```
INFO     2017-11-14 05:08:10,743 connectionpool.py:788] Starting new HTTPS 
connection (1): api.instagram.com
ERROR    2017-11-14 05:08:11,734 spiderlogic.py:110] ('Connection aborted.', 
error(13, 'Permission denied'))
ERROR    2017-11-14 05:08:11,736 baselogic.py:48] Traceback (most recent call 
last):
File "D:\Python\GitHub\tagzy\api\logic\spiderlogic.py", line 88, in 
__save_instagram_account_info__
req = requests.get(api_uri, params = params)
File "D:\Python\GitHub\tagzy\lib\requests\api.py", line 71, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\GitHub\tagzy\lib\requests\api.py", line 57, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\GitHub\tagzy\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "D:\Python\GitHub\tagzy\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python\GitHub\tagzy\lib\requests\adapters.py", line 453, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

My sdk version

Google Cloud SDK 177.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.62 bq 2.0.27 core 2017.10.20 gsutil 4.28

Comment: Any firewall active?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Downgrade requests module to version **2.1.0** using following command.

`pip install requests==2.1.0`

**Solution 2:**

As per [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests#issuing_an_http_request) you can monkey patch requests to play nicely with Google App Engine.

install requests-toolbelt:

`pip install -t lib requests-toolbelt`

Then in your main.py file (or equivalent):

```
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
```